# Fake User Profiles Flooding the Site

Tags: discussion, site-health

Recently I have noticed a huge increase in users on the page counter. I wondered whether this is organic or rather bot behaviour and had a look at the [users by creation date](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate). It seems that 7 days ago, [first * *Car Insurance* * user profile](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/1124/average-rate-quote-car-insuran) has been created with about a hundred of others in the following day with somewhat increasing frequency.

They all point to an assumed car insurance company with telephone number 1-844-909-0831 / +1(844)909-0831. There is also some search engine filler text that repeats car insurance bazillion times.

All in all, this can be quite detrimental to the site if it gets out of hands and so perhaps should be barred at the early stages. What do you think? What is the policy for dealing with fake accounts here at SE?

Comment: I'll need to work on this after finishing my weekly grocery shopping, it's pretty widespread https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there are thousands network-wide, and SE is working on a solution to getting rid of them. I can also delete manually, but that's much more tedious -- either way, this will take a little bit of time to clear out :)

The slightly good news is, they are only spam profiles, not spam posters.

Comment: Yeah, spam posters would be definitely much worse. I am glad to hear that solution is being looked for site-wide. :)